# Partitioning a List of Dictionaries in Python According to a Value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

I have a coding challenge requires me to create a logic that partitions a list of dictionaries into three new lists of dicts. The new lists need to have the same number of experienced and inexperienced personnel. The original list has an even number of experienced and inexperienced personnel. I have no idea how to form the logic for this challenge. Here is a shortened version:

```
mylist = [
    {'name': 'Jade', 'height': 64, 'experience': 'n'}, 
    {'name': 'Diego', 'height': 60, 'experience': 'y'},
    {'name': 'Twee', 'height': 70, 'experience': 'n'}, 
    {'name': 'Wence', 'height': 72, 'experience': 'y'},
    {'name': 'Shubha', 'height': 65, 'experience': 'y'},
    {'name': 'Taylor', 'height': 68, 'experience': 'n'}
]
```

The new dicts need to have equal numbers of experienced and inexperienced personnel like this:

```
newlist_1 = [
    {'name': 'Diego', 'height': 60, 'experience': 'y'},
    {'name': 'Jade', 'height': 64, 'experience': 'n'},
]

newlist_2 = [
    {'name': 'Wence', 'height': 72, 'experience': 'y'},
    {'name': 'Twee', 'height': 70, 'experience': 'n'},           
]

newlist_3 = [
    {'name': 'Shubha', 'height': 65, 'experience': 'y'},
    {'name': 'Taylor', 'height': 68, 'experience': 'n'}
]
```

I am keeping the original list, so in the end there needs to be a total of four collections.

Comment: > new dicts need to have the same number of experienced and inexperienced personnel
You mean that new **lists** need to have the same number of experienced and inexperienced personnel?
Same across 3 lists or same in each of three lists?

Comment: Does that mean that the original list has exactly 3n dict() elements where n is even and exactly half of the elements have experience: 'y' and other half is 'n' ?

Comment: Hi yes sorry, that should have been "new lists". I've updated the post. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi yes, the original list has an even number of experienced and inexperienced personnel. I've updated the post. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def make_teams(my_list):

  # divide the member list in two
  experienced = list()
  novice = list()
  for record in my_list:
    if record.get('experience') in ['Y','y']:
      experienced.append(record)
    else:
      novice.append(record)

  # stitch the two lists together as a list of tuples
  teams = zip(experienced, novice)

  # build a dictionary result starting with the member list
  results={
    'members':my_list
  }

  # update results with each team
  for i in range(0,len(teams)):
    results.update(
        {'newlist_%s'%(i+1):list(teams[i])})

  return results
```

---

Will produce the following...

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(make_teams(mylist))

{'members': [{'experience': 'n', 'height': 64, 'name': 'Jade'},
             {'experience': 'y', 'height': 60, 'name': 'Diego'},
             {'experience': 'n', 'height': 70, 'name': 'Twee'},
             {'experience': 'y', 'height': 72, 'name': 'Wence'},
             {'experience': 'y', 'height': 65, 'name': 'Shubha'},
             {'experience': 'n', 'height': 68, 'name': 'Taylor'}],
 'newlist_1': [{'experience': 'y', 'height': 60, 'name': 'Diego'},
               {'experience': 'n', 'height': 64, 'name': 'Jade'}],
 'newlist_2': [{'experience': 'y', 'height': 72, 'name': 'Wence'},
               {'experience': 'n', 'height': 70, 'name': 'Twee'}],
 'newlist_3': [{'experience': 'y', 'height': 65, 'name': 'Shubha'},
               {'experience': 'n', 'height': 68, 'name': 'Taylor'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 lists - one with experienced and one with inexperienced and build whatever lists you need from that, something like:

```
experienced = [worker for worker in mylist if 'y' == worker['experience']]
inexperienced = [worker for worker in mylist if 'n' == worker['experience']]
list1, list2, list3 = map(list, zip(experienced, inexperienced))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try slicing the list of dictionaries into three seperate list

```
list1 = mylist[0:2]
list2 = mylist[2:4]
list3 = mylist[4:6]
```